# How to use library which include Xamarin.iOS in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin.ios

I created dll which include Xamarin.iOS by Visual Studio 2017.

```
using JavaScriptCore;
using Foundation;

namespace JSCore
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static int Test()
        {
            JSContext jsContext = new JSContext();
            jsContext[new NSString("arg1")] = JSValue.From(2, jsContext);
            jsContext[new NSString("arg2")] = JSValue.From(2, jsContext);

            var jsResult = jsContext.EvaluateScript("arg1 + arg2;");

            return jsResult.ToInt32();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this library in Unity.

I put this dll in Unity Plugins folder and write script (call `MyClass.Test()`).

In Editor, there is no error. But when I build project, some error appeared.

```
IL2CPP error for method 'System.Void ObjCRuntime.Runtime::set_UseAutoreleasePoolInThreadPool(System.Boolean)' in assembly '/Users/[MyName]/Documents/JavaScriptRuntimeTest/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Xamarin.iOS.dll'
Additional information: Build a development build for more information. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I read error sentence. I think this is the version error about `System.dll`.

Xamarin.iOS reference `System.dll 2.0.5.0`.

Unity's API Compatibility Level is `.NET Standard 2.0`.

How to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's Mono runtime isn't compatible with Xamarin, so the only possibility to use your library is to remove the IOS part.

Comment: So I can't use JavaScriptCore in Unity ?

Comment: no, if you need to evaluate JS then maybe this will help you : https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/jurassic-javascript-runtime-interpreter-for-unity-2345. If you use javascriptcore just for json parsing , go for JSON.NEt

Comment: I already tried Jurassic. See [this close question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108253/is-there-any-javascript-runtime-engine-works-on-mult-platform).